# In a dynamically changing fields using jquery same field gets posted twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a form where I have a text field which will be changed on radio button selection.

```
$("#id_radio1").click(function() {
    $("#multi_language").hide();
    $("#single_language").show();
});
$("#id_radio2").click(function() {
    $("#single_language").hide();
    $("#multi_language").show();
});
```

Say suppose id_radio1 and id_radio2 are two radio buttons and selecting each changes the form fields differently. Now I was able to do it successfully.
My problem is when I submit the form after single language button is clicked the values are stored as multi as the values of the multi language hidden fields are submitted overridding the values of first.CAn I disable the other field without interference of the same on submission.

How can I correct this?

I'm new to such problem. I want the field to be submitted only once.i.e, if single language field is selected single should be posted and not multi(as it is working now) and when multilanguage is selected multi should be posted.How can I correct this now with the following code.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5T6Y/2/)
**I have other fields common for both single and multi language in the same form as well, whose values are not changed on submission**

Now, in the console I see there are two posts for the same fields in the response i.e. one for single language and other multi language.

Comment: @gulty I posted it in Fiddle

Comment: @gulty Is it the right way I have done, or should I do som thing else

Answer (score 0):

You can format your html code as below just if you want to pass the value of the checked field to some other script

```
        <form method="post">
          <input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="single" />
          <label for="id_radio1">Single Language</label>
          <input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="multi" />
          <label for="id_radio2">Multi Language</label>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

and in your Jquery Code, you can do this

```
            $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log($("input:checked").val()); //do whatever you want with the checked value
             })
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t2eZ/)

Comment: Hi Chakravarthy, I have mentioned that I have other fields prior to radio buttons in this form.How can I post those fields as well.

Comment: Include the other fields inside <form> tag prior to radio input tags, you can get all the values as a array using $("form").serializeArray();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *disabled* attribute to prevent an element from being sent like so:

```
$("#id_radio1").click(function() {
  $("#multi_language").attr('disabled','disabled').hide();
  $("#single_language").removeAttr('disabled').show();
});
$("#id_radio2").click(function() {
  $("#single_language").attr('disabled','disabled').hide();
  $("#multi_language").removeAttr('disabled').show();
});
```

Since they are no hidden fields but just hidden by css it should prevent it from being submitted

Comment: I will check and get back to you

Comment: TypeError: "#multi_language".attr is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have one text input, then in your server-side code simply check which radio button was selected and set the value of the server-side variable accordingly before committing data.

e.g. In PHP for instance:

```
$language = $_POST['language'];

if($_POST['name_radio1'] == 'single'){
  some_function_committing_single_language_value($language);
} else {
  some_function_committing_multi_language_value($language);
}
```

Or have one text input and set the form's onsubmit handler with a Javascript function to insert a hidden field with a name such as 'language_single' or 'language_multi' based on the radio button selection, and set that hidden input's value to the textfield's value.